# Discord.js bot joins then leaves

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, ytdl

i built a discord.js bot that joins when someone use its command, but it's only working if the video has high views, I tried to use unlisted YouTube videos, some videos that I uploaded and low-viewed videos but it's not working, it just joins the voice channel then leaves.

```
 if (message.content == "!sodium") {
     if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("You have to be in a voice channel");
     message.member.voice.channel.join().then(VoiceConnection => {
         VoiceConnection.play(ytdl("https://youtu.be/30p-iRH9z2c")).on("finish", () => 
         VoiceConnection.disconnect());
         message.reply("started...");
     }).catch(e => console.log(e))
 };
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors

Comment: Side note 
```VoiceConnection.disconnect());
         message.reply("started...");```
shoud be indented more than
```VoiceConnection.play(ytdl("https://youtu.be/30p-iRH9z2c")).on("finish", () => ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by adding `{ filter: 'audioonly' }`.